# Form HTML + JSP

Tags: html, jsp

pessoal criei uma pagina html com um formulario simples e estou querendo usar as infos no jsp

1) classe java "Calculo":

```
package principal;
public class Calculo {
    public int n1;
    public int n2;
    public int resultado;
}
```

2) form html

```
<form method="POST">
    soma<input type="radio" name="soma"> | subtracao <input type="radio" name="sub"><br>
    valor1:<input type="text" name="valor01"/><br>
    valor2:<input type="text" name="valor02"/><br>
    <input type="submit" value="calcular"/><br>
</form>
```

3) jsp (dentro do html)

```
<%
    Calculo c1 = new Calculo();
    int valor1 = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("valor01"));
    int valor2 = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("valor02"));

    c1.n1 = valor1;
    c1.n2 = valor2;

    c1.resultado = valor1+valor2;
    out.print(c1.resultado);
%>
```

Estou utilizando o tomcat 7, o erro é o seguinte, na linha 21:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /teste.jsp at line 21
```

Linha 21:

```
int valor1 = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("valor01"));
```

Ja tentei de tudo, e ainda nao consegui, alguem pode me ajudar? vlw

Comment: seria interessante colocar todo o stacktrace do erro

Answer (score 1):

O JSP está no mesmo arquivo que esse formulário certo? Na primeira vez, você não tem nenhum parâmetro passado, então ele tenta converter nulo para inteiro, e causa a exceção. Você precisa checar se você tem os valores no request antes de usá-los. Tente isso:

```
<%
if (request.getParameter("valor01") == null || request.getParameter("valor02") == null) {
  out.print("<p>Informe os valores</p>");
} else {
  Calculo c1 = new Calculo();
  int valor1 = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("valor01"));
  int valor2 = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("valor02"));

  c1.n1 = valor1;
  c1.n2 = valor2;

  c1.resultado = valor1+valor2;
  out.print(c1.resultado);
}
%>
```